# Is matlab supporting arabic?

Tags: matlab

I'm arabian and i can't work easy in matlab case of 'matlab Don,t support arabic' such as string of popup menu as shown in codes

```
x=get (handles.popupmenue,'string')
y=get(handles.popupmenue,'value')
z=x(y,:)
z=string(z)
switch strip (z)
case 'كلمة'
set(handles.text1,'string','هذا')

%%%when I save that all of arabic words changed into '?'
case '????'
set(handles.text1,'string','???')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it might be that you miss a few tiny details in your case

```
 switch strip (z)
    case 'كلمة' :            // ":" is missing 
      set(handles.text1,'string','هذا')
      break;         // here might be also a break welcome  to end the case
```

the ???? shows that the unicode  which is used is not understand by whatever is in between or your browser page or the js interpreter . (Wrong unicode setting).
Same result i get if i copy and paste russion VBA code from a website in my "german/US" VBA. The code itselv is fine - but any comments (sure tey are russion language ones) are gone to become question marks. Same with code from asia. Code is fine  - comments or strings are "gone". It simply means that the codepages are not the same or some speak unicode and someones not. So take some time to figure out which unicde page is used. UTF9 or UTF16 or ... Then you can write a function if needed to translate that codes.
1980 we have had 256 characters on the computer. That was all. Even those was over character number 128 different. By some companys even the below 128 was working just with luck. Then some comes out with unicode. Which enhanced the 128 bytes mess to a 64000 byte mess :D  ONE Unicode set would be even for chinese and the rest of the world  enough but .... This mappings are till today a joy of everyone ...

Comment: Where do the 128 bytes come from? 256 characters means 1 byte per character. UTF-16 is takes 16 bits per character.

Comment: I show an example and Iam not interestedin";"or"end"but i atentioned to the problem